# PATCH /contacts/v1/contacts Not Update The Contacts Attributies Sometime

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, mobileconnect

I have a SSJS Code, Which have QueueMO request and Update Contact Rest API request.

Once i got the result OK in QueueMO function, the next code is Update Contact step (this one: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updateContacts.html ).
I'm using this Update Contact Rest API to update the MobileConnect Demograhics First & Last Name. Most of the time this working fine, but sometimes, the Update Contacts not update the First & Last Name and I received the Message As IsContactKeyNew, Means Contact record not found. How to Fix this.